# What is the expression that is less harsh than "lost my hope"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

Consider the following scenario:

> The service centre of a very popular product X is very bad in every aspect of customer satisfaction; in fact, just once, I submitted my product for repair, they took almost 2 moths to return it to me and finally when it reached my hand the transportation had made it even worse. The experience of only that time has made ***my pivot of belief feeble*** (or) ***my faith weak*** upon the product. If this happens one more time, I would surely loose my hope on them.

I don't feel the bolded parts are the right way to express this feeling. It's like, I still did not lose my hope, but if the same thing happens one more time, I surely will.

Comment: *The experience **has dented my faith** in the product.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Idiomatically, you could say that the experience has **shaken your faith**,  or that it has **raised doubts**, or that it has **given you second thoughts** about the product.

Also there are several other issues with your paragraph (e.g. *fixation* does not mean *the process of being repaired*, and you use *loose* where you need *lose*); you might rewrite it along the lines of:

> The service center for the very popular Product X is bad in every aspect of customer satisfaction.  In fact, the one time I had to send in my product for repair, they took almost 2 months to return it to me; and when I finally got it back, it had been damaged in shipping and was in worse condition than when I'd sent it in.  That experience has really shaken my faith in the product; if I have another experience like that one, I'll probably give up on it.

Comment: But if really the product is not shipped and the service center is within the country, will using _shipping_ be proper then?

Comment: I wrote "Damaged in shipping" because I thought based on your original that the service center had actually fixed it, but the company that shipped it back to you had damaged it.  If the service center didn't actually fix it at all, then you'd want to write something a little different.

Comment: Perhaps something like "when I finally got it back, they hadn't actually fixed the problem at all; in fact, they'd made it worse than before!"

Answer (score 3):

I think '*my faith weak*' is a good option to use. Just keep the following in mind:

- The noun *faith* is used with the preposition '**in**'. Your sentence should read '***... has made my faith in the product weak.***' Although, since you're talking about the customer-service of the company, why don't you say that instead of 'product'?
- Don't say reached my hand, 'reached me' sounds much better.
- '*worse*' is a **comparative adjective**, (the order goes bad -> worse -> worst), so saying 'even more worse' is incorrect since the word 'more' is used to make regular adjectives of 2 or more syllables a comparative. (eg. beautiful -> more beautiful). '... transportation had made it even worse...' is appropriate.
- Instead of 'The experience of only that time', use '*that one experience*'.

Hope I helped! :)

Answer (score 1):

[I am taking it that the idea is that you are one step away from “losing hope”.  So…]

Also…

“I am on the verge of giving up!”  [“Verge” is like “edge”.]

“That would be the last straw!”

Another relevant expression is the following.  It means that I am now determined to do something, so that the situation is fixed — or at least I will try to.
“I have had it up to *here* [gesturing — hand at neck]!”

————

“The experience of only that time has made my pivot of belief feeble (or) my faith weak upon the product.”
—>
“That one experience has shattered my faith in the product.”  [This means that you *have* lost hope.]
“That one experience has nearly shattered my faith in the product.”  [This means that suddenly you are *near* to losing hope.]

p.s.  “… weakened my faith” would mean that you still have faith, but you want to be reassured by being treated properly next time (and otherwise your faith would be even more weakened).